# Rotating a polygon so a specific side is on the bottom

Tags: math, svg, vector, graphics, geometry

I'm trying to find the angle it would take for me to rotate a polygon so that a specific side is completely horizontal and on the bottom.

For example, a shape like this:

[image]

Needs to be rotated so the side with the red square on it is on the bottom and completely horizontal, like this:

[image]

So far I've tried several approaches but all end up having strange edge cases where the angle is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have coordinates of two vertices of this edge (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) in counterclockwise order, then rotation angle is

```
RotAngle = atan2 (y2-y1, x2-x1)
```

Comment: What do you mean by counterclockwise order? This works but I'm finding tons of scenarios where the result is reversed - the entire shape needs to be above the marked line, not below it. Orientation is important here.

Comment: Standard vertice ordering is counter-clockwise, i.e. edge P2P3 turns left after P1P2 edge. You can check for order with cross product sign, and invert the result if sign is negative